# String Concat Speed In Java

Tags: java, performance, string

I was prototyping an SQL query quickly, and instead of doing it the correct way, I just decided to slam through it with a bunch of string concats, the entire time thinking that this would be extremely slow, but it didn't matter because I was just testing the query. To my suprise, Java says that this code take 0 ms to complete? Doesn't it take more time do this with `+` rather than `StringBuilder` or similar?

```
long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
String load = "";
for (String s : loadFields)
    load += s + ", ";

String sql = "SELECT ";
sql += load + "sum(relevance) AS 'score' " +
        "FROM ( ";

for (int i = 0; i < searchFields.length; i++) {
    sql += "SELECT ";
    sql += load;
    sql += rels[i] + " AS relevance FROM articles WHERE " +
            searchFields[i];

    sql += " LIKE '%" + terms[0] + "%' ";
    for (int z = 1; z < terms.length; z++)
        sql += "AND " + searchFields[i] + " LIKE '%" + terms[z] + "%' ";

    if (i != searchFields.length - 1) sql += " UNION ALL ";
}

sql += ") results GROUP BY " + load.substring(0, load.length() - 2) + " ";
sql += "ORDER BY score desc, date desc";
System.out.println("Build Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t) + " ms");
```

Yes, this is very ugly, but the point is not to iterpret the SQL, but to tell me why this is so fast.

`Build Time: 0 ms`

**Edit:** I ran the test 10000 times with 20 terms, and it took about 10 seconds, so about 1/10 of a millisecond. Now that I think about it, it is pretty obvious that this isn't that much to computation unless I start getting really long strings.

Comment: if you want to measure the speed of something like this, you need to run it many, many times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're only doing 29 concatenations - I should hope that takes less than a millisecond.

If you want to test this code against a StringBuilder implementation, you should iterate it 10,000 times or so (and do proper JVM warm-up).

#### Benchmark

I was curious to see what the exact difference is in this case, so I converted your code to use `.concat()` and `StringBuilder` and benchmarked with 10,000 iterations (2,000 warmup), with 5 fields and 20 terms, all of them randomly generated 32 char strings.

Results (in milliseconds):

```
   plus: 19656 (0.5/ms)
 concat: 5656  (1.77/ms)
builder: 578   (17.3/ms)
```

Comment: The arrays that are iterated over are usually around 20 in size, so it just doesn't concat this once, but multiple times. Is there some sort of optimization that Java is doing that I am not seeing?

Comment: Seems that it is not as much computation as I thought it was. Thanks for the help!

Comment: +1: You should time how long it takes after it has been called 10,000 (i.e. after it has warmed up)  If you use StringBuilder and prebuild the parts of the SQL which don't change each time, it will be much faster.

Comment: @Ricky: Yes, I didn't count the loops, but it's still much faster than what can be measured at millisecond level.  The main problem is still that you aren't using `PreparedStatement` with bind variables: hand-rolled SQL is just never a good idea, and will have more of an effect on overall performance than whatever string concatenation strategy you use.

Answer (score 2):

The strings you are concatenating are very short. Try using strings of length 100,000 or more (write some code to generate huge strings) and then do that several hundred times. With short strings and only a few concats, the difference is too small to be measurable.

Comment: That seems to increase the time ALOT, thanks for the input, it seems that it just really isn't alot of computation with small string sizes.

Comment: @Ricky Button: Exactly. Smarter algorithms usually only matter when the input size is big enough.

Answer (score 1):

You are measuring the time using the millisecond clock.

- The absolute smallest interval that you can measure is one millisecond.  That is typically OVER ONE MILLION cycles of the hardware clock.  A current generation CPU can do an lot of computation in that time.
- It is possible that the actual granularity of the millisecond is a number of milliseconds.  (Unlikely with a current generation OS, but I remember the days when the clock tick was 20 milliseconds.)

Either way, it is not surprising that the measured time is usually zero.

---

To get a meaningful measurement, you need to put a loop around that code and run it *hundreds of thousands* of times.  And put another loop around that to run the test repeatedly ... until the measured time stabilizes.

Finally, this is going to be allocation intensive, and you need to **include** the amortized GC times.  (An optimized version using StringBuilder will win in part by NOT being so allocation intensive.)

Comment: Thanks, it is not nearly as much computation as I originally thought.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that doing `+` means that java is creating a copy of your original string and adding the new part to the copy everytime. I would think that would be slower but in any case it would definintly seem to take more memory than `StringBuilder`. It seems that it would be much more efficient to have a `StringBuilder` that you kept adding to and only `.toString` or `String.valueOf()` when you are done adding things.